# SharePoint 2016 and "Shared Role" Application with Search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search, 2016, index-component

I want to install SP 2016 using "Shared Roles" and use 2 servers that have the role "Application with Search" so I get High Availability. I just want to use the search capabilities of SharePoint, I will have javaScript code call the REST endpoints to query the search.

With that said, I will NOT need the "Front End and Distributed Cache" servers, is this ok and supported?

So basically I will now get HA with just 2 servers, since I only need the search components.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You must have Distributed Cache in the farm; a farm without that service is unsupported. It sounds like you may want to use the Custom role instead so you can start what you need + Distributed Cache on the two servers.

Comment: You think if I do Application, Distributed Cache and Search Roles on two servers would work and still get HA, or will I need to go to 4 servers now to get HA?

Comment: You can do 2 servers for HA, you just need to use the custom role.